# Facebook SDK share post auto cancel on iOS 11

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, ios11

I use Facebook SDK's `FBSDKShareDialog` to allow users to share a Facebook post on their wall. However, on iOS 11, it doesn't work anymore and the call always ends with the `func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!)` delegate method. How to fix this?

Code:

```
let sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: UIImage(named: "image.jpg"), userGenerated: true)!
let sharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
sharePhotoContent.photos = [sharePhoto]
sharePhoto.caption = "Caption"

FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: sharePhotoContent, delegate: self)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share With Facebook Not Working Anymore on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396524/share-with-facebook-not-working-anymore-on-ios-11)