# Facebook ShareDialog crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS if Facebook app is not installed (iOS 11.3 XCode 9.3)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-share

Until iOS 11, I was using `SLComposeViewController` for sharing with Facebook, but now it's deprecated.

So I've added Facebook SDK's ShareDialog to my project.

If Facebook App is **installed** share process is done successfully, but if Facebook app is **not installed** Facebook SDK throws `EXC_BAD_ACESS`. You can see the screen where it crashed. Crash occurs in `SDKSharingDelegateBridge.swift` class.

[image]

If app not installed it should supposed to open WebView or give some error. It shouldn't crash and give me no error.

Since there is no log for the crash I only have `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

My environment:

- XCode 9.3
- Swift 3.3
- iOS 11.3
- FacebookShare (0.3.0) (from CocoaPods)

Have anyone came across to this situation? Thx already.

Below is the code snippet from the app which is copied from the offical docs. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/share-dialog)

```
var shareContent: LinkShareContent?

if let urlstring = urlStr, let url = URL(string: urlstring) {
    shareContent = LinkShareContent(url: url, quote: initialText)
}

let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: shareContent!)
shareDialog.mode = .native
shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
shareDialog.completion = { result in
    // Handle share results
}

do {
    try shareDialog.show()
}
catch {

}
```

Comment: Please post the actual error instead of an image of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396524/share-with-facebook-not-working-anymore-on-ios-11

Comment: this is the actual error, it doesn't give any logs as I've said in my thread.

Comment: @Khushbu this is not the case for me. Share is working for me and my pods are up to date. Facebook SDK crashes if Facebook App is not installed when using share dialog this is the case for me.

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to add the SDK?

Comment: try to change `shareDialog.mode = .native` to `shareDialog.mode = .web` , native mode main

Comment: @A.Munzer I've tried automatic it always opens webview even if app is installed. I can try to check if app installed call .native if not .automatic. But SDK should handle it by itself.

Comment: check that you are using this function in correct way in your AppDelegate: 

` func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if (url.scheme?.contains("fb"))!{
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url as URL?, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
            )
        }
        
        return true
    }`

Comment: Nope it's not related to this function also. I'm using func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any?) -> Bool { } but I've tried what you've given.

Answer (score 1):

Until better answer I've fixed it like below.

```
if  UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fb://")!){
    shareDialog.mode = .native
}
else {
    shareDialog.mode = .automatic
}
```

Comment: Facebook documentation now uses "fbapi" key instead of fb. This worked for me: if  UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fbapi://")!){
            shareDialog.mode = .native
        }
        else {
            shareDialog.mode = .automatic
        }